# How to duplicate rows to backfill data to a certain date based on other column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 7 variables and millions of rows.  I would like to create rows to "back-fill" data to a specific point in time based on the instance which has already been coded for.

Instance is calculated by Year, ID, Var1, Var2, and Number.  You'll notice that the date of the first instance varies based on those "Groups". For the groups that the first instance is not 1/1/2015, I need to "back-fill" their data until 1/1/2015.

Here is the initial data frame:

```
Date <- c("4/1/2015", "5/1/2015","1/1/2015","2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015")
Year <- 2015
ID <- c("123456", "123456", "234567", "234567", "234567", "234567", "234567", "123456", "123456", "123456")
Var1 <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)
Var2 <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11)
Number <- c("0001", "0001", "0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0002","0002","0002")
Instance <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(Date, Year, ID, Var1, Var2, Number, Instance)
```

Here is my expected output:

```
Date <- c("1/1/2015","2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015", "5/1/2015","1/1/2015","2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","1/1/2015","2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015")
Year <- 2015
ID <- c("123456","123456","123456","123456", "123456", "234567", "234567", "234567", "234567", "234567", "123456","123456","123456", "123456", "123456")
Var1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1)
Var2 <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11)
Number <- c("0001","0001","0001","0001", "0001", "0001","0001","0001","0001","0001","0002","0002","0002","0002","0002")
Instance <- c(0,0,0,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(Date, Year, ID, Var1, Var2, Number, Instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `complete` after grouping by the columnss of interest

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, ID, Var1, Var2, Number) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq(floor_date(Date, 'month')[1], max(Date), 
        by = '1 day'), fill = list(Instance = 0)) %>%
  select(names(df))
# A tibble: 15 x 7
# Groups:   Year, ID, Var1, Var2, Number [6]
#   Date        Year ID      Var1  Var2 Number Instance
#   <date>     <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 2015-01-01  2015 123456     1    10 0001          0
# 2 2015-01-02  2015 123456     1    10 0001          0
# 3 2015-01-03  2015 123456     1    10 0001          0
# 4 2015-01-04  2015 123456     1    10 0001          1
# 5 2015-01-05  2015 123456     1    10 0001          2
# 6 2015-01-01  2015 123456     1    11 0002          0
# 7 2015-01-02  2015 123456     1    11 0002          0
# 8 2015-01-03  2015 123456     1    11 0002          1
# 9 2015-01-04  2015 123456     1    11 0002          2
#10 2015-01-05  2015 123456     1    11 0002          3
#11 2015-01-01  2015 234567     2    10 0001          1
#12 2015-01-02  2015 234567     2    10 0001          2
#13 2015-01-03  2015 234567     2    10 0001          3
#14 2015-01-04  2015 234567     2    10 0001          4
#15 2015-01-05  2015 234567     2    10 0001          5
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : "to" must be a finite number.

Comment: "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : "to" must be a finite number.

Comment: @MelissaDureiko. I guess in your example, it is working, right?.  So, it must be something related to the original data where there could be missing values or can you check if the `Date` column is `Date` class

Comment: In this example it works, however my actual data set goes until 7/1/2019.  I checked, and the Date column is in fact a date class.  In the console the error is reading "All formats failed to parse.  No formats found."

Comment: @MelissaDureiko. Your date is in format `%m/d/%Y` or `%d/%m/%Y`.May be theere are multiple formats in your date column?

Comment: My format in the date column is just as it was above (%Y-%m-%d), so I just changed the code you provided to `Date=ymd(Date)` and `by=('1 month').  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @MelissaDureiko. Yes, if that is the only format, it should work correctly.  Can you pinpoint it to a smaller data where the error occurs.  In thtat case, you can dput that example data for me to take a look at tit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196323/discussion-between-melissa-dureiko-and-akrun).